# PHP: Is it ok to pass $_GET as a parameter of a constructor?

Tags: php

Is it ok to pass $_GET as a parameter of a constructor?

I'm guessing not but would like some constructive arguments that will hopefully raise the following please?

1. Best strategy for dealing with $_GET at the client
2. Security issues around $_GET

Thanks in advance for your interest.

Comment: What do you mean by at the client?

Comment: It depends on what the constructor's class is supposed to do.

Comment: Client just being the area where you are dealing with input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  The data in `$_GET` is just like any other data.  You just need to remember that data from the user can never be trusted.

If your classes are sanitizing data for use, generally this isn't an issue anyway.  Just be extra cautious to avoid things such as SQL injections and XSS.

Comment: So I can allow $_GET anywhere in class, it doesnt have to be sanitized outside of the class just as long as its sanitised before going into the database?

Comment: @Steve, you should always be sanitizing what goes into the database anyway.  Even if the source data is just your own code, leaving that up to whatever class is dealing with the database.  Plus, you never know when you might need to use something not-so-malicious, like a `'` or a `"`, and you need that to work!

Comment: haha thanks Brad I get that, what I was asking was, does it matter where you sanitize it? i.e. Client, Constructor or Custom method

Comment: Depends on what you mean by sanitize.  If you are sanitizing data for inserting into a database, that should be done at the point of database insertion.  If you are stripping HTML, JavaScript, etc., most people choose to do this at the display side of things.  The idea is, you keep your data plain and only modify it for specific purposes when you use it for those purposes.  Some people though will just strip out HTML and what not upon receiving the user input, and this is also fine.  At least for database though, you should definitely only do that where you have your DB functions.

Answer (score 4):

Your question could use a little clarification, but if you're talking about an object constructor function `__construct()`:

It wouldn't harm anything to pass `$_GET` to an object constructor, however it's unnecessary because the `$_GET` superglobal is already available to any class you create.

Subjectively, I tend not to access `$_GET $_POST $_SESSION` inside classes directly myself very often.  Usually I'll pass in the array values from the superglobals that I'll actually be needing.  This is strictly a personal preference though, because it's always looked weird to me to access them inside class methods.  There's nothing wrong with doing it.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me to use `$_GET` or some other variable int he constructor.  Who cares if it is available to the class... it is just a parameter.  He may want to use his class in another context later.

Comment: While `$_GET` is indeed available to classes as a superglobal, if you rely on `$_GET` inside your classes, the reusability decreases. It also makes testing of your clases difficult, since you have to recreate having `$_GET` populated. In my opinion, constructors should rely on values being passed into it, not on superglobals.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is a variable like any other, and can be used as such. You can pass it anywhere you would pass another variable.

Since $_GET contains user-provided data, you should always clean that data before performing operations on it. Escape the data before inserting it into a database or outputing it as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could argue that one of the points of using OO programming and classes is encapsulation. By passing though a global parameter you don't break the arrangement, but you do compromise it slightly.

Technically there is no issue as long as you are assigning the values of the $_GET parameter within your constructor. If you're actually assigning a reference, or calling $_GET within your methods, you're leaving yourself open to the possibility of the functionality of your class being compromised by changes outside.